# Capturar ação de um formulário em um botão

Tags: html, formulário, div

Boa Tarde
Fiz um filtro normal, porém para eu conseguir formatar o filtro de uma forma mais efetiva, quero tirar o Botão da Div, porém quando faço isso o botão para de funcionar por não estar junto com o formulario

Como faço para que o botão continue funcionando? 
Segue os codigos

```html
 <div id = "filtro">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
  <style disabled>
    

    #filtro {
    border-style:double;
}

#button1 {
    width: 120px;
    position: inherit;
    right: 10px;
    background-color: #e00505;
    font-size: 12px;
    FLOAT: right
}

h4 {
    font-size: 18px;
    border-style: inset;
}

select {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 124px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 3px;
}

section label {
    width: calc(100% / 4);
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
}

section {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
h4/ {
    border-style:double;
}


@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
    section label {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
</style>
<h4 style="text-align: center;">Personalize o seu Kit de Segurança</h4><br><br>

<form action="#" id="form">

    <section>
        <label>
            <b> Tipo do seu Kit </b><br>
            <select name="speed" id="speed" style=" ">
                <option desable>Selecione</option>
                <option>Residencial</option>
                <option>Comercial</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <label>
            <b>Qualidade de Seu Kit</b><br>
            <select name="files" id="files" style=" ">
                <option desable> Selecione </option>
                <option value="HD">HD</option>
                <option value="Full HD">Full HD</option>
                <option value="Analógica">Analógica</option>

            </select>
        </label>
        <label>
            <b> Quantidade de Câmeras </b><br>
            <select name="number" id="number" style=" ">
                <option desable> Selecione </option>
                <option>1 Câmera</option>
                <option>2 Câmeras</option>
                <option>3 Câmeras</option>
                <option>4 Câmeras</option>
                <option>5 Câmeras</option>
                <option>6 Câmeras</option>
                <option>7 Câmeras</option>
                <option>8 Câmeras</option>
                <option>9 Câmeras</option>
                <option>10 Câmeras</option>
                <option>11 Câmeras</option>
                <option>12 Câmeras</option>
                <option>13 Câmeras</option>
                <option>14 Câmeras</option>
                <option>15 Câmeras</option>
                <option>16 Câmeras</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <label>
            <b> Selecione a Marca </b><br>
            <select name="salutation" id="salutation">
                <option desable selected>Selecione</option>
                <option>Intelbras</option>
                <option>Hikvision</option>
                <option>Outras</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </section>
  
<BR>
    <BR>
   
 
</form>
 
</div>
<br>
<br>
 <button class="kd-filter-button" id="button1">Ver resultados</button>
```

Aproveitando a pergunta, se puderem me indicar a melhor forma de eu fazer o chamado dos dados que preciso, qual a formula posso usar nos option?

Comment: O que é que deixa de funcionar? O seu script? Se for o script, edite sua pergunta e inclua também o seu JS

Comment: No caso eu não deixei o formulário totalmente funcional, pois preciso pegar as informações junto a plataforma que utilizo (tray) de quais comandos preciso utilizar para chamar os dados certos.... assim que tiver as informações vou colocar as chamadas certas...
Por enquanto estou fazendo a "carcaça" do formulário, e no caso preciso que o botão funciona sem estar dentro do formulário, portanto no momento não possui o JS e nem precisa pois a plataforma faz esse trabalho e só preciso das chamadas

Comment: Mas funcione fazendo o que? O que não está funcionando?

Comment: Funcione filtrando com as opções selecionadas, 1 ou mais seleções

Comment: Ou preciso de um JS para fazer essa função?

Comment: Precisa sim...!

Comment: Então poderia me dar uma ajuda para desenvolver esse JS?

Comment: Cara Java Script não é minha área, não entendo quase nada, mas as vezes aparece alguém com conhecimento nesse área para te ajudar. Infelizmente nessa pergunta não tenho conhecimento suficiente para te ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, o problema é que o HTML está mal formatado de forma geral. Tente seguir padrões não misturando HTML com CSS e metatags sempre na head.

O botão precisa, sempre, estar contido no ; ele não funcionava pois estava fora. Abaixo seu código com o botão dentro do formulário, permitindo o evento de submit.

Espero que ajude

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<style disabled>
    

    #filtro {
    border-style:double;
}

#button1 {
    width: 120px;
    position: inherit;
    right: 10px;
    background-color: #e00505;
    font-size: 12px;
    FLOAT: right
}

h4 {
    font-size: 18px;
    border-style: inset;
}

select {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 124px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 3px;
}

section label {
    width: calc(100% / 4);
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
}

section {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
h4/ {
    border-style:double;
}


@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
    section label {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" id="form">
<div id = "filtro">
<h4 style="text-align: center;">Personalize o seu Kit de Segurança</h4><br><br>
<section>
        <label>
            <b> Tipo do seu Kit </b><br>
            <select name="speed" id="speed" style=" ">
                <option desable>Selecione</option>
                <option>Residencial</option>
                <option>Comercial</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <label>
            <b>Qualidade de Seu Kit</b><br>
            <select name="files" id="files" style=" ">
                <option desable> Selecione </option>
                <option value="HD">HD</option>
                <option value="Full HD">Full HD</option>
                <option value="Analógica">Analógica</option>

            </select>
        </label>
        <label>
            <b> Quantidade de Câmeras </b><br>
            <select name="number" id="number" style=" ">
                <option desable> Selecione </option>
                <option>1 Câmera</option>
                <option>2 Câmeras</option>
                <option>3 Câmeras</option>
                <option>4 Câmeras</option>
                <option>5 Câmeras</option>
                <option>6 Câmeras</option>
                <option>7 Câmeras</option>
                <option>8 Câmeras</option>
                <option>9 Câmeras</option>
                <option>10 Câmeras</option>
                <option>11 Câmeras</option>
                <option>12 Câmeras</option>
                <option>13 Câmeras</option>
                <option>14 Câmeras</option>
                <option>15 Câmeras</option>
                <option>16 Câmeras</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <label>
            <b> Selecione a Marca </b><br>
            <select name="salutation" id="salutation">
                <option desable selected>Selecione</option>
                <option>Intelbras</option>
                <option>Hikvision</option>
                <option>Outras</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </section>
</div>

 <button class="kd-filter-button" id="button1">Ver resultados</button>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: A sim, sei que ele não estava funcionando por estar fora, mas precisaria que ele funcionasse fora mesmo, pois quero personalizar o formulário de uma forma que o Botão acaba atrapalhando...
Entende? Se não me engano é possível fazer com a tag <script> mas não entendo dela o bastante para conseguir desenvolver
E esta misturado com CSS porque como trabalho com a Tray depois de terminar tudo eu vou dividir em arquivos e fazer as chamadas... mas no momento o importante é ser funcional